# Cocoa Multiple-Value Boolean Bindings, Using Logical OR

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

So I have a view that I want hidden depending on a BOOL

I do this by Cocoa Bindings

```
[view bind:@"hidden" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"someBOOL" options:bindingOptions];
```

My problem is now I want another BOOL to be bound to the view as well.

So if either of these BOOLs return `YES`, I want the `view` to be hidden

```
[view bind:@"hidden" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"someBOOL2" options:bindingOptions];
```

The problem is that it looks like by default, having two BOOL bindings to the same view defaults to a logical AND operation, and so it doesn't matter if either `someBOOL` or `someBOOL2` evaluate to `YES` if the other one doesn't also evaluate to `YES`

So does anybody know if there's a way to make it so these programmatic boolean bindings use the logical OR operator?

This is the only relevant documentation and information I could find:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/Concepts/BindingTypes.html

> Multiple-Value Bindings
>
> Multiple-value bindings allow multiple bindings to be created for a
>   single binding. Creating a binding with the first binding
>   automatically causes a second binding to be exposed, and so on.
>
> For example, if you bind to the enabled binding, a binding called
>   enabled2 is exposed. If you bind enabled2, the object will expose
>   enabled3, and so on. All these binding values are then used together
>   in returning the final value of the binding.
>
> Multiple-value bindings are always read-only.
>
> There are four variations of multiple-value bindings.
>
> Multiple-Value Boolean Bindings Multiple-value Boolean bindings are
>   used to determine if an object is editable, hidden, or enabled. The
>   resulting value of the binding is derived by forming the logical AND
>   or logical OR of the values of the exposed bindings. The logical
>   operation used depends on the specific binding.

Comment: For the second binding as you've shown it, you're still using the name "hidden". That **replaces** the first binding. If you want to use multiple-value bindings, the second one needs to using the binding name "hidden2".

Comment: Ah yeah it says it right there in the documentation, wasn't reading carefully enough.  Do you know if it's possible to switch between the logical AND/OR?  It says "The logical operation used depends on the specific binding." which makes it sound like I have no control over it

Comment: "The NSView is hidden if a logical OR operation on all the hidden bindings results in a Boolean value of YES." [NSView hidden](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSView-SW3).

Comment: Yup that's what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second binding as you've shown it, you're still using the name "hidden". That replaces the first binding. If you want to use multiple-value bindings, the second one needs to using the binding name "hidden2".

As noted by @Willeke, the hidden binding uses a logical OR for multiple-value bindings. Good thing that's what you want, because, no, you can't change it. :)